# How to find similar file names across subdirectories using Linux command line?

Tags: linux

I want to search for files that have the term "climate" in their file names.

```
-- FolderA  
  |-- BUILDINGS_CLIMATE_CHANGE.txt 
  |  
  |-- Subfolder  
    |  
    |-- BUILDINGS AND CLIMATE.pdf
```

I am in the folder "FolderA", and I run the following command:

```bash
ls -la | grep -i "climate"
```

This returns the file `BUILDINGS_CLIMATE_CHANGE.txt` located in the "FolderA" directory, but it does not return the file `BUILDINGS AND CLIMATE.pdf` located in the "Subfolder" directory.

Which command should I use to get the file paths of both files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With `grep`:

```bash
ls -laR | grep -i "climate"
```

---

Notes:

- `ls` command lists the files and directories in a directory, but it does not do so recursively.
- `l` specifies that `ls` should use the long listing format, which displays more information about each file or directory, including permissions, owner, group, size and modification time.
- `a` specifies that `ls` should include hidden files and directories in the listing.
- `R` option specifies that `ls` should list files and directories recursively.

#### With `find`:

```bash
find . -type f -iname "*climate*"
```

---

Notes:

- `find` command searches, by default, the specified directory and all its subdirectories recursively.
- `type f` specifies that we only want to search for files.
- `iname` specifies that we want to do a case-insensitive search for the files.
- `*` is a wildcard that matches any number of characters.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I am curious - why does grep not work here?

Comment: You are welcome. Grep is actually working as intended, searching for the word "climate" in the output generated by `ls -la`. However, because `ls -la` does not include subdirectories in its output, grep is not able to search within those directories. To include subdirectories, the `-R` flag must be included with the `ls` command.